# After first match match the whole string

Tags: php, regex

I have a small problem, I try to make my own password regex for PHP.

This is my expression:

```
/([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[!?]+)/
```

After it matches it stops, e.g. `a1?` is the first match, `a2!` is the second match, but I want it to match the whole string:

```
a1?a2!
```

After that, I tried this expression:

```
/([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[!?]+){6,12}/
```

However, it doesn't match anything.

Comment: Do you mean you want `/(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[!?]+)+/`? See https://regex101.com/r/zN1tZ1/1. Or do you intend to match *the entire string*? Then use [`'/^(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[!?]+)+$/D'`](https://regex101.com/r/fV2rE2/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your `/([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[!?]+){6,12}/` regex matches 6 to 12 sequences of 1+ letters, 1+ digits and 1+ `!` or `?` symbols.

Actually, you want to match 1 or more of such sequences, then use a mere `+` quantifier:

```
'/^(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[!?]+)+$/D'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV2rE2/2)

Since you need the *validation* pattern, I think you need to match an *entire* string, so you need anchors `^` and `$` and use the `/D` modifier to disallow a trailing `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

this regular expression will for your password "a1?a2!" -

> ((?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[?!])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[?!]).{6,20})

But you should use standard for password like -

> ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}

This regular expression is for: Minimum 8 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character